What does ‘D’ in GADP (glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate) stand for?
Wikipedia says glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate can be abbreviated as G3P, GA3P, GADP, GAP, TP, GALP or PGAL, and many resources seem to use GADP as its abbreviation.
I have no idea where ‘D’ came from. What is ‘D’ in GADP?

For "GAPD" I'd assume "glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase", but for D in "GADP" I can only think of either D-isomer, or the reference to "dihydrogen" in IUPAC name "2-hydroxy-3-oxopropyl dihydrogen phosphate", but neither of these appear particularly logical to me. Good question.

PubChem provides a list of synonyms, amongst which the most reasonable lead to the acronym GADP is "Glyceraldehyde, 3-(dihydrogen phosphate), D- (8CI)"
Acronyms don't always have to be very logical, preferably short and memorable as for NMR experiments.

Just thinking of HOHAHA ...

I am going to reiterate what @andselisk said in the comments. The "D" in GADP can also refer to the D-isomer of the molecule. Notice in the below reaction that Fructose-1,6-bisphosphate is abbreviated as F1,6BP which make sense (the letter and digits goes from left to right). By this logic, glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate should have been abbreviated as DGAP but as @BuckThorn said, acronyms don't have to be logical.

Picture from Wikipedia
